# options.data.indexOf is not a function when doing an ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: options.data.indexOf is not a function`.

I've looked for a solution and I found out it's probably because of the jQuery version (I have jQuery 3.3.1 btw). But most problems were trivial like `$(window).on('load', ...)` instead of `$(window).load(...)`. For this one I have no idea what's actually going on.

So here's the code:

```
function changePhotoPOST() {
   var form = document.getElementById('someFormName');
   var formData = new FormData(form);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "...someUrl...",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onFailed
   });
}
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="someFormName">
      <input type="text" value="@User.Identity.Name" name="Email" hidden />
      <input id="file" type="file" onchange="changePhotoPOST()" name="File" hidden />
      <a class="some classes" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click(); return false">Some text</a>
 </form>
```

I use a styled link to open the file picker and as soon as a file is picked I submit the form. Still, the form might as well be a normal form with visible inputs, I don't think that's important.

So when the file is picked the the form is submitted, I get the mentioned error. From what I understand indexOf is used on 'data' for some reason? Is there a syntax error somewhere? Can I solve this without changing the jQuery version?

Comment: Well, the obvious problem is that the id of your form in the HTML is "ChangePhotoForm" and you're getting a form with the id "someFormName" in your JavaScript.

Comment: I replaced the name in JS but forgot to do it in form. So the id is fine, I checked. I will edit the post.

Comment: I'd try it with `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`.

Answer (score 0):

use form data like :

```
function changePhotoPOST() {
 var form = $("form").serialize();
   var formData = new FormData(form);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "...someUrl...",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onFailed
   });
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.` from this `var form = $("#someFormName").serialize();`. So this is not working.

Comment: [The constructor for `FormData` takes an `HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have pasted the exact code you are using but your element id is wrong.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dstf2qjw/) seems to work (I don't have an url which recieves the data but the request is sent).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ChangePhotoForm">
      <input type="text" value="asdsa" name="Email" />
      <input id="file" type="file" onchange="changePhotoPOST()" name="File" hidden />
      <a class="some classes" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click(); return false">Some text</a>
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function changePhotoPOST() {
   var form = document.getElementById("ChangePhotoForm");
   var formData = new FormData(form);

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myUrl",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onFailed
   });
}

function onSuccess(response) {
   console.log("response", response);
}

function onFailed(response) {
   console.log("response", response);
}
```

It is using jQuery 3.3.1;
[image]

Comment: Yes, but I see you are using a different version of jQuery. To reproduce this you would have to use 3.3.1. The question is first of all how to do it with jQuery 3.3.1, I will only change the version as a last resort if needed. It has to be possible thought, right?

Comment: It's using 3.3.1, check my edit, I removed the jquery in the code, not needed

Comment: Hm you are right (not familiar with this website). Well, something's definitely off on my part then. Can't figure out what... I'll look later and see if I have an update on this, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yea, you can try to start from my example (see if that works) and then adapt it to your code and see when it fails.

Comment: Uf, had the time to look over this now, seems like some bundles were messed up and didn't include jquery in development. I don't work alone on this and I didn't think that this would be the problem... Once I included it properly it works fine.